# How to get the Distinct Record in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I display all records in a single coulmn if the name is duplicate in sql server.

```
SELECT * INTO #temp
FROM (
Select 'S1' Name, '1' Age, 'A' X, 'B' Y UNION ALL
Select 'S1', '1', '', 'B'
) A

Select *
From #temp
```

[Output]
[image: 1]

The expected result is:

[image: Expected result as an image]

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. Explain what you want and post any code as text in the question itself. Post sample data and what results you expect. Images can't be copied or executed.

Comment: Besides, the title asks one thing and the question text something different. If you want distinct result rows use `SELECT DISTINCT`. It's unclear what `display all records in a single column` means. Are you asking how to concatenate values? That's done with `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server and `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL

Comment: `distinct` would be a good start point

Comment: Do you want to find all non-unique names? Also, this site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE]. Please show an actual attempt, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, clarifies what you want to achieve.

Comment: If a value is same it should not concat, It should display only 1 value , For example The output should be like S1 , A, B, 1.  It should concat only if the column value is NULL.

Comment: He could also be looking for a group by  name, but its a guessing game here

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output. And an attempt would be nice too.

Comment: @Bohemian: Please see the attached Example Image for Input, The Output should be in 1 coulmn like S1 , A, B, 1. It should concat only if the column value is NULL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: STRING_AGG will concat the two column values, Issue here is it should concat only if the column value is NULL

Comment: @NagarajuKukudala the issue is you haven't explained what you want *in the question itself* yet. Edit the question and include what you expect. We can't guess what you mean. `display all records in a single column` makes little sense. Do you want to receive a single value containing `1AB1B` ? Probably not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My Apologies, I have attached the Required Output in the question.

Comment: Post text, not links to images to who knows where. There's a reason this question has two downvotes. Also explain the *logic* by which the result was selected. You want the first matching row based on some order (which one)? Last matching row? The maximum value per column?

Comment: From the SQL tag's description; *Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used.*

Comment: You mention `NULL` in a comment, but your example uses `''`. Please update your question with full, complete, requirements using enough example data to describe the scenarios you need to address, and the Exact results you require for that example data. Please read this for more detail; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) *(Learning how to make a good MRE will teach you testing methodology and make you a better developer.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for the expected output aren't clear. It could be the "last" row based on some order, or each column returns the maximum value in a group.

If the maximum value is needed, the following should work:

```
SELECT Name, Max(Age) as Age, Max(X) as X, Max(Y) as Y
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Name
```

If the "last" row is needed, there must be a way to order the results. Table rows have no implicit order. Assuming there's an incrementing ID, one could use `ROW_NUMBER` to find and return the latest row per group:

```
with rows as 
(
    SELECT ID,Name,Age,X,Y,ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC) as RN
    FROM SomeTable
)
SELECT Name,Age,X,Y
FROM rows
WHERE RN=1
```

This will split (partition) the data by name and calculate a row_number based on descending order inside each partition. Since the rows are ordered by ID descending, the first row will the the latest one.